# Display image instead of combobox

Tags: wpf, image, combobox, drop-down-menu

I am looking for a way to display an image which when click drops a combo box containing items for the user to select from.

I currently have the items displayed in a combo box, it would be sufficient for me to overwrite the template used by the combo box and permanently displaying the same image next to the drop down arrow, instead of the selected value.

How easy is this to achieve? What properties should I be looking to set to achieve this?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in the past. Problem is that the ComboBox shows the selected value as the "main" element next to the togglebutton. What i did, was to create a new [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094.aspx), copied the whole combobox template and added a `ContentPresenter` on top of the existing in the togglebutton content. The existing ContentPresenter shows the selected item, you can overwrite its Content `Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"` and show something else, like your image for example.